# "Twisted" universal enveloping algebra?

Tags: lie-algebras, deformation-theory

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a $k$-Lie algebra, and $Q: \bigwedge^2 \mathfrak{g}^* \rightarrow k$; define $U_Q(\mathfrak{g})$ to be the quotient of the full tensor algebra over $\mathfrak{g}$ by the ideal generated by elements of the form $x\otimes y - y \otimes x -[x,y] - Q(x,y)$. This definition does not depends properly on $Q$ but only in its cohomology class in the Chevallay cohomology.

Has anyone seen this kind of algebra appear somewhere and/or has a name for them? They appeared to me from a deformation...

Comment: I take it that $Q$ is a cocycle?  If so, then what you are defining is a quotient of the universal enveloping algebra of the central extension of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: Yes, it should be a cocycle, forgot to tell it.
Where can I find about central extensions?

Comment: Any treatment of Lie algebra cohomology should do it.  I think it even goes back to the original paper of Chevalley--Eilenberg, but I'n not sure.


Comment: Indeed, it's §26 in the Chevalley--Eilenberg paper: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=24908

Comment: By the way, older issues of AMS journals are now freely available.  For the Chevalley-Eilenberg paper see:
http://e-math.ams.org/journals/tran/1948-063-01/S0002-9947-1948-0024908-8/home.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These algebras were considered by Ramaiengar Sridharan a long time ago. See [Sridharan, R. Filtered algebras and representations of Lie algebras. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 100 1961 530--550. [MR0130900](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0130900) (24 #A754)]

If the map you are using to twist is not a Chevalley-Eilenberg cocycle, then things are ugly. In particular, you do not get a PBW-basis of the algebra (the cocycle condition is equivalent to the BPW property, in fact; this was in the general context of quadratic Koszul algebras a few years ago)

By the way: I call them *Sridharan enveloping algebras*, and I have heard others do the same.

Comment: That was one of the very first papers I ever read :)

Comment: Rediscovery of neglected older mathematics will (I confidently predict) be a major pastime of future generations, unless we somehow persuade fewer people to take up the subject -;)

Comment: @Mariano: It's *Ramaiyengar* and not Ramiengar Sridharan